# How to update a table using trigger every 30 days?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, triggers, cron

Hi I want to create a MYSQL trigger that updates my users's table. My Scenario is this : I have users table in which there is a field called **Balance**. Each Reseller assgins balance to its users to: **Yes or No**. Now if the reseller sets the balance of users to Yes, then i store the current date and time into database into a field called Reset_date. Now i want to count from today 30 days and when 30 days are completed i want to update users's balance to **No** So from the day then balance has been set to yes, after 30 days balance should be reverted to No.

I Guess i should also be using **CRON JOB** for this, as i have multiple reseller and multiple users. So the reset data is different for each of them.

I mean for user1 the reset date is today and for another it maybe different so might be cron job be needed here. So please guide me on how to use this cron job as well.

Below is my Table Structure for Users and Resellers:

**Reseller**

[image: Resellers]

**Users**

[image: users]

Comment: i think you should run cron every midnight to check if date has exceeded 30 days. if yos you can update to `No`

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Thanks but can we add a  trigger to cron job?

Comment: you should set in your server

Comment: you got your doubt cleared??

Comment: No @NiranjanNRaju i dont know how to create a trigger firstly then i can think of creating a cron job

Comment: I have answered, how to trigger cron. check that. it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger a cron job.

- You should write a function in controller to do what you require(change `yes` to `no` if date has exceeded 30 days.
- You should make sure that, you controller funtion doesn't have any session related to it.

I have added following images , refer them

[image]

I have added a cron which runs once in a day. and in your server, it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: interface?? I didnt get you.

Comment: i am using CENTOS as my server so where do i find this settings?

Comment: as soon as you login, where you see phpmyadmin, filemanager, search for `cron`, it will be present somewhere below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91462/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-rajan).

Comment: Okay but i am still working locally so firstly i want to test it here

Comment: ya... you can directly test by url only.

Comment: Can you tell me what should be my update code? as i mentioned i have multiple resellers and multiple users

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption about using cron job is correct. 
You can run a corn job every midnight using the following format:

```
0 0 0 1/1 * ? *
```

In your job, you can check for records with dates which are **30 days** old and is assigned **YES**.
Then you can update this records and assign status to **NO**

Comment: Thanks but can you please post how to add this to cron job? i mean can we add a trigger to cron job?

Comment: NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
or
NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY

use this in your query to fetch 30 days old records

Comment: when i add balance = Yes i do this :   $this->db->set('reset_date',unix_to_human(strtotime("+30 days")));